# How to make a div pop up on overflow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image]I want to display a `div(with className='invoice-info')` on hover of the `icon(which is in table cell)` like this:

```html
<div
    style={{ position: "relative" }}
    onMouseEnter={() => setHoveredInvoiceId(result.gsCustomersID)}
    onMouseLeave={() => setHoveredInvoiceId()} >
    <i className="icon-container invoice-icon" id={"csInvoiceIcon" + 
         result.gsCustomersID}></i>
    <div className="invoice-info">Hello</div> //this is displayed conditionally
</div>
```

I wrote some styles for the div like this:

```css
.invoice-info {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    width: 10vw;
    height: 10vh;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 1em;
    bottom: -6em;
}
```

But due to the width of `table-cell` is small enough to fit only icon, the div is hidden. I gave z-index to make it float but it is not working. I want a floating div on hover. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoice cell has `overflow:hidden` property. It worked after changing it to `overflow:visible`

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS instead of JS that will have some performance gain.

you can use something like this:

```
.invoice-info{
   display: none;
   // your other styling
}

.icon-class:hover ~ .invoice-info{
 display: block;
}
```

~ is general sibling selector in CSS

Comment: thanks for your response. But here performance is not my issue. I am asking about making entire div show up with z-index

Comment: change the sequence of the elements, put invoice-info above .icon